# SSL Handshake: why server side waits 100+ ms between server-side ChangeCipherSpec and Finished?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jsse, sslcontext

I'm writing a simple HTTP server by SSLSocketFactory and here is my Java codes:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      ks.load(TestEcho.class.getResourceAsStream("/localhost.pfx"),
              "****".toCharArray());
      KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      kmf.init(ks, "****".toCharArray());
      SSLContext sslc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      sslc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

      // try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4443)) {
      try (ServerSocket server = sslc.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(4443)) {
           while (true) {
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                // ((SSLSocket) socket).getSession();
                socket.getInputStream().read();
                socket.getOutputStream().write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\nok".getBytes());
                socket.getOutputStream().flush();
           }
      }
 }
```

But the performance is much lower than Tomcat Http11Protocol (bio). I catch the TCP dumps and find a 100+ms gap between server-side ChangeCipherSpec and Finished. But when I connect to Tomcat there is no such gap.

The TCP dump of my above codes are:

```
[127.0.0.1:1962 Connected at 00:58:21.718]
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:21.718] // ClientHello
0000:0000  16 03 03 00 C3 01 00 00-BF 03 03 59 82 04 AD 44   ...........Y...D
...
0000:00C0  02 03 02 01 02 02 01 01                           ........        
[127.0.0.1:1962 Received at 00:58:21.781] // ServerHello & Certificate & ServerHelloDone
0000:0000  16 03 03 0B EB 02 00 00-4D 03 03 59 82 04 A8 14   ........M..Y....
...
0000:0BE0  12 0D 53 CB B6 20 64 BC-8E 77 3A 0F 0E 00 00 00   ..S.. d..w:.....
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:21.812] // ClientKeyExchange
0000:0000  16 03 03 00 46 10 00 00-42 41 04 ED DD 67 FB 22   ....F...BA...g."
...
0000:0040  39 50 1F 50 F2 12 62 A7-3D C8 FE                  9P.P..b.=..     
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:21.828] // Client ChangeCipherSpec
0000:0000  14 03 03 00 01 01                                 ......          
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:21.828]  // Client Finished
0000:0000  16 03 03 00 50 8E DB DC-39 07 9B 68 36 17 BB 44   ....P...9..h6..D
...
0000:0050  B3 5E 91 FF E8                                    .^...           
[127.0.0.1:1962 Received at 00:58:21.890] // Server ChangeCipherSuite
0000:0000  14 03 03 00 01 01                                 ......          
[127.0.0.1:1962 Received at 00:58:22.046] // Server Finished, but delayed 156ms !!!
0000:0000  16 03 03 00 50 71 68 70-ED 8F D6 73 11 94 DD F4   ....Pqhp...s....
0000:0010  D9 A4 1F 60 BA 48 43 B0-4B 53 EF 66 E5 59 F2 8B   ...`.HC.KS.f.Y..
0000:0020  DD CE D7 D5 8F C4 68 A2-87 07 92 A9 3B D9 9B 3B   ......h.....;..;
0000:0030  DD DE 1A 71 6F 87 8D 59-17 6F 8F 94 2C 89 01 DA   ...qo..Y.o..,...
0000:0040  E9 7D 08 E2 F2 FC 54 BF-FA 8D 45 F8 7B B0 29 8D   .}....T...E.{.).
0000:0050  CE 87 CF 81 E1                                    .....           
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:22.046] // HTTP Request
0000:0000  17 03 03 00 A0 73 85 EE-93 BC 66 94 76 6D 49 74   .....s....f.vmIt
...
0000:00A0  DE C2 BE DD 46                                    ....F           
[127.0.0.1:1962 Received at 00:58:22.062] // HTTP Response
0000:0000  17 03 03 02 70 E8 CF 13-B4 E0 4F 32 8E 6F 37 74   ....p.....O2.o7t
...
0000:0270  DD 5B FB 99 9D                                    .[...           
[127.0.0.1:1962 Sent at 00:58:22.062] // Disconnect
0000:0000  15 03 03 00 40 42 BC E5-B7 B2 E4 B5 22 D2 DF 75   ....@B......"..u
...
0000:0040  B8 59 B2 89 FB                                    .Y...           
[127.0.0.1:1962 Disconnected at 00:58:22.062]
```

In the test to a Tomcat server, the TCP dump is like:

```
...
[127.0.0.1:1968 Received at 00:58:50.312] // server-side ChangeCipherSpec & Finished
0000:0000  14 03 03 00 01 01 16 03-03 00 50 03 0D D0 FE 94   ..........P.....
0000:0010  5D 0B 22 60 62 46 F3 29-D9 37 B7 D1 42 60 5A 6A   ]."`bF.).7..B`Zj
0000:0020  93 C8 1F CF D8 B9 81 7D-DD 3D A9 1E A0 F0 C0 05   .......}.=......
0000:0030  11 C8 C4 B9 31 16 E5 1E-2F 43 EA 45 2A F0 E8 BF   ....1.../C.E*...
0000:0040  9E BD 20 84 8E 5A 1A 57-0B 31 32 BE 5E 6C B3 F3   .. ..Z.W.12.^l..
0000:0050  6A 00 95 D3 75 32 03 35-83 3D 12                  j...u2.5.=.     
...
```

Are there usage problems with SSLContext, KeyManagers or SSL Handshake in my Java Code?

Answer (score -1):

After reading tomcat's source code, I removed the delay simply by enabling **TCP_NODELAY**:

```
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                // ((SSLSocket) socket).getSession();
```

**UPDATE-1**

And tomcat enables TCP_NODELAY for each accepted socket. See tomcat-coyote's source (8.0.x) `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties` line 155:

```
/**
 * TCP_NO_DELAY option. JVM default used if not set.
 */
protected Boolean tcpNoDelay = Boolean.TRUE;
```

and 2 `setProperties` methods, which is called once socket accpeted.

**UPDATE-2**

JVM disables TCP_NODELAY by default, which means *Nagle's Algorithm* can delay sending small bytes. Obviously, *Server Finished* is delayed by Nagle's algorithm.

Lots of articles about **TCP_NODELAY** can be googled.

Comment: If it was enabled by default, how did enabling it fix it? Or change anything at all?

Comment: sorry. changed to *tomcat enables TCP_NODELAY for each accepted socket*

Comment: Same question. Nothing changed, in the socket or, materially, in your answer. If it was already enabled, how did enabling it fix the problem? or change anything at all.

Comment: But JVM disable TCP_NODELAY by default, which means *Nagle's Algorithm* can delay sending small bytes (obviously *Server Finished* is delayed by Nagle's algorithm). Lots of articles about **TCP_NODELAY** can be googled.